# Which view store SHOW SLAVE STATUS data in mysql 5.7 and mysql 8?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know which views can I get this information in both version without `use show slave status` command, I need to use standard sql commands.

Ie:

instead of execute.

```
show slave status\G;
```

And look for `Seconds_Behind_Master` column

```
....
   Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
....
```

I'd like to query something like it using SQL:

```
select Seconds_Behind_Master from view_here;
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear, can you take a moment to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 5.7 replication information is stored in `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` tables.

I would recommend to read Jesper Krogh's excellent blog post [Replication Monitoring with the Performance Schema](https://mysql.wisborg.dk/2018/10/05/replication-monitoring-with-the-performance-schema/) which also contains several SQL examples.

Comment: Thanks. MySQL 8 has several timestamp columns to check it in performance_schema as the references say, but I did not find any column for it in mysql 5.7.

Example: replication_applier_status_by_worker has much few columns in MySQL 5.7 than MySQL 8.